# Can we access bucket using bucket endpoint with python sdk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, boto

Can we access bucket with bucket endpoint like .s3.amazonaws.com using python sdk. i don't want access bucket with following bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you need to access it this way because the s3 endpoint is a fixed part where only thing changes is the name of your bucket (because it's global).

But, in the end, what you are looking for is not possible unfortunately. You need to provide bucket name for accessing the bucket and running operations on it.

Verified by boto3 documentation and here you can check:
[S3 Boto documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object)